# Find a homeomorphism between $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R^n}:0<\|x\|\leq1\}$ and $Y=\{y\in\mathbb{R^n}:\|y\|\geq1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X=\{x\in\mathbb{R^n}:0<\|x\|\leq1\}$
and $Y=\{y\in\mathbb{R^n}:\|y\|\geq1\}$

Find a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

I was thinking of $f:X\to Y$ with $f(x) = x+n$, but I don't think it will work for $f^{-1}:Y\to X$.

I don't think I have the right idea for this question.

Comment: Did you mean hom**e**omorphism in the title?  How about $y=x/||x||^2$?

Comment: Think of $n=1$, for example; I think my example is an [involution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $f:X\to Y$ as $f(x)=\dfrac x{\lVert x\rVert^2}.$

Note that this $f$ is its own inverse.

Comment: How about $f(x)=\dfrac 1{\lVert x\rVert^2}$? Does it still works? Or am i missing something?

Comment: I’d say that maps $X$ into $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^n$