# Constructing homeomorphism between (0,1] and $[1,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I am trying to construct a homeomorphism between (0,1] and $[1,\infty)$ in the real line. But I am not sure how to construct a bijective continuous(also inverse is continuous) function for it. Can somebody help? Thank you...

Comment: Why not $x\mapsto\frac1x$?

Comment: Note title question differs from the body question.

Comment: Is it $[1,\infty)$ as in the body or $(1, \infty)$ as in the title? If it’s the former, the Jose’s answer works, but if it’s the latter, it’s a little bit tricky (maybe impossible, but I haven’t thought about it so I’m not sure).

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I just fixed the title.

Comment: @paulinho just out of curiosity, is it also possible for latter to be homeomorphic?

Comment: @paulinho If it's the latter no homeomorphism exists.

Comment: I guess you're right, as then it we take out 1 from the domain the latter set will be disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I thought that might be the case. But @kim you can still find a (discontinuous) bijection between the two.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102684/find-a-homeomorphism-between-x-x-in-mathbbrn0-x-leq1-and-y-y-in) in $\mathbb R^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a self-inverse, continuous bijection from $(0,1]$ to $[1,\infty)$.